# Why did the bountied questions increase so rapidly?

Tags: support, bounty

I don't get it, just yesterday, the number of bountied questions on Stack Overflow was about 50, and today, 500! What could have caused this increase?

Comment: Do you mean that the bounty increased, or that the score on the question increased rapidly after a bounty was placed on it?

Comment: @RobertColumbia I think she's referring to the total number of bountied questions on Stack Overflow, which [as of the time of writing](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=bounties) is 490. I might be wrong, though, and she would need to clarify if/when she migrates this to Meta Stack Overflow.

Comment: @RobertColumbia I mean the number of questions with bounties increased. On stack overflow, not stack overflow meta.

Comment: @AnnZen Could it be that once you looked with a filter applied, and another time without that filter?

Comment: This is a support question asking for help - the answer is helpful, not sure what the downvotes are for. This isn't necessarily something that's easy to figure out on your own. Also, if the answer is correct, this isn't no-repro! Please don't vote to close it as such.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You had a filter applied, so you saw only part of the questions.

You can see a filter is in use by watching for the orange indicator next to the filter name:

[image: custom filter applied]

To get back to full list of questions, just go back to homepage, or the full questions list.

Comment: Thanks. I always go to stack overflow with [python] tag.